# Simple CSS MasterPage layout

Tags: html, css

I'm helpless, tried my best understanding CSS but it's just not for me.

I would like to make a really simple MasterPage:

- at the top a div of full width and height 40px (1)
- at the bottom also a div of full width and height 40px (2)
- in the middle:

  - on the left: a div of width 200 px (3)
  - on the right side of the left div: a div with contentPlaceHolder (4)

What I would like to get is: if i make some site that uses my master page and place a panel in the contentPlaceHolder that has width 800px, I would like my site to adjust to it - top, middle and bottom divs to have their width of 1000px (200 + 800). I also wouldn't like (and I have a huge problem with that) the (4) to move down if I resize (shrink) the browser window - I would like all the divs to be blocked.

This is my master page html:

```
<div>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="links">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

What kind of CSS do I have to write to make this finally work?

Comment: I have responded to the comment you've left on one of my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have checked into this or not, but we use the [YUI-Grids CSS Framework](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/) for our layouts. It keeps us from having to spend a lot of time on CSS, which we are not great at being developers.

There is even a [grid builder](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/) which will let you graphically layout a page, and then copy and paste the required HTML to make it happen :)

Comment: +1 yui grids are pretty decent. add yui-fonts to that too. you might want to also check out 960grid and the holy grail templates to find the best for your need.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent floated divs from being "squeezed" out of the alignment you want, you usually use either width or min-width.

For example, in this code the div containing the links and content will never be smaller than 1000 pixels.  If the screen is smaller than 1000 pixels, a scrollbar is displayed.

```
<div style="min-width: 1000px">
    <div class="links"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

You could also use width instead of min-width:

```
<div style="width: 1000px">
    <div class="links"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

The difference between the two is simple: if you specify min-width, the div CAN grow to be larger if it needs to.  If you specify width, the div will be exactly the size you specified.

Be aware that min-width is not supported by IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick stab at specific CSS/Markup for this problem.

Markup:

```
<!-- Header, etc. -->
<div class="contentView">
    <div class="links">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer, etc. -->
```

CSS:

```
.contentView {
    /* Causes absolutely positioned children to be positioned relative to this object */
    position: relative;
}

.links {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
}

.content {
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

You might want your footer to be "sticky."  Check here for information on that: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

How appropriate this is depends on precisely what the design calls for.  This makes the links section more of a floating box on the left than a column for example.

This ends up looking like this (.content is green, .links is red):

[image: An example of this markup.]

Comment: well ok, but what about header and footer?

Comment: The header should just be a matter of dropping the HTML in where I have the "Header, etc." comment.  For a simple footer (bottom of the content) you can just do the same where I have the "Footer, etc." comment.  If you want the footer to be stuck to the bottom of the document, see the link in my answer directly beneath the CSS code.  Leave another comment if you have a specific question about implementing those.